# Why is log4net creating an empty log file before configuration?

Tags: c#, log4net, app-config

My log4net is creating an empty log file in my debug/release folders for some reason.  An example filename is "(null) 20150409.txt".

I'm not sure how to tell it not to do that.  I am programmatically configuring log4net, but this empty file is created before the configuration routine is actually run, perhaps as a result of the App.config file itself.

Here is the App.config file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>

  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,Log4net"/>
  </configSections>

  <log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL"/>
      <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender"/>
    </root>
    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender, log4net">
      <!--http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html-->
      <!--http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html-->

      <!--<param name="File" value="C:\Images\log-file.txt" />-->
      <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="%property{LogFileName}"/>

      <staticLogFileName value="false"/>
      <param name="AppendToFile" value="true"/>
      <rollingStyle value="Date"/>
      <datePattern value="' 'yyyyMMdd'.txt'"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
  </log4net>

  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
  </startup>

</configuration>
```

Here is the C# configuration code (which appears to work fine):

```
log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["LogFileName"] = LogFileName;  
// Full path to log file
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
Log.Debug("CV3 Launched with log file located here: " + LogFileName);
```

How do I prevent this empty file from being created without affecting the rest of the logging which is working fine?

Comment: Did you try to use ignore section handler in `app.config`? That should avoid the empty file.

Comment: Where/how in app.config do I put the ignore section handler?  Can you please provide a snippet? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have `[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]` in your AssemblyInfo.cs file?

Comment: I believe is because of the `datePattern` element. Also, you're using a RollingFileAppender, but when it rolls it will not use the log file name you've supplied, but will create one based on the datePattern..

Comment: http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure_overload_5.html It shows how to.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. Doing research around ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836737/issues-in-log4net-with-dynamic-filenaming-in-rollingfileappender), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462534/log4net-dynamic-filename-not-working) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562108/how-do-i-use-a-globalcontext-property-in-a-log4net-appender-name)), the error is because that you have called `log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();` **before** setting log4net properties.

If you are like me, very likely that you have **configured log4net another time** in the file `AssemblyInfo.cs`. Because the logger in AssemblyInfo would be loaded first, it would create another (null) file every time your app start.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

@nb1forxp , have you tried this way?

**Create a new locking model**

```
public class MyLock : log4net.Appender.FileAppender.MinimalLock
{
      public override Stream AcquireLock()
      {
            if (CurrentAppender.Threshold == log4net.Core.Level.Off)
                  return null;

            return base.AcquireLock();
      }
}
```

**Config**

```
<threshold value="OFF" />
<lockingModel type="Namespace.MyLock" />
```

Refers from [How to disable creation of empty log file on app start?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533403/log4net-how-to-disable-creation-of-empty-log-file-on-app-start).